# extract string including whitespaces within string (java)

Tags: java, string, whitespace, substring, extract

I have a string that contains 2 integer numbers separated by whitespace followed by any character string which includes whitespace.

**Example:**

```
23 14 this is a random string
```

How do I extract `this is a random string`?

The integers aren't guaranteed to be double digits therefore I can't figure out how to use indexOf and substring to extract this data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `exampleString.substring(exampleString.indexOf(" ", exampleString.indexOf(" ")+1) + 1);`

Comment: you can take a look at java.util.Scanner class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. I can't believe how much code some people write to do the simplest of things...

Here's an elegant, one-line solution:

```
String remains = input.replaceAll("^(\\d+\\s*){2}","");
```

Here's a test:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    // rest of String contains more numbers as an edge case
    String input = "23 14 this is a random 45 67 string";
    String remains = input.replaceAll("^(\\d+\\s*){2}","");
    System.out.println( remains );
}
```

Output:

```
this is a random 45 67 string
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`split(String regex, int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
String s = "23 14 this is a random string";
String[] arr = s.split(" ", 3);
System.out.println(arr[2]);
```

**OUTPUT:**

> this is a random string

Comment: This is the simplest solution, I think you should mark this as the answer. :)

Comment: @Geoff btw, this isn't the simplest solution (see mine for that), and will explode with ArrayIndexOutOfBounds if the remaining text is blank (ie input is `"12 34"`, which is not excluded in the question), because there will be no 3rd element from the split

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "23 14 this is a random string";
str = str.replaceAll("[0-9]", "");
str = str.trim();
```

Comment: .. and what if 'random string' also contains numbers?

Comment: Then you use Eng Fouad's solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a combination of the above answers, `regex` + `replaceFirst`.

```
String s = "23 14 this is a random string";
String formattedS = s.replaceFirst("\\d+ \\d+ ", "");
```

This removes the first two numbers separated by a whitespace, regardless of how big the numbers are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringTokenizer and if you know you'll have 2 numbers, just ignore the first two elements in the array.

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("23 14 this is a random string");

int i = 1; // counter: we will ignore 1 and 2 and only append

while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
   // ignore first two tokens
   if (i > 2) {
             sb.append(st.nextToken()); // adds remaining strings to Buffer
   }

   i++;  // increment counter
} // end while

// output content
sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(youString, " "); //whitespaces as delimeter

int firstInteger=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
int secondInteger=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
```

similarly rest of the tokens..

you can make a definite array..

and store rest of the tokens in a string array like this..

```
while(st.hasMoreTokens())
{
 ar[i]=st.nextToken();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly... If your `String` follows a pattern and you need to extract something from it, try to use `Regex`. It's made for this.

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^\\d+ \\d+ (.*)$");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher("23 14 this is a random string");

if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

That outputs:

```
this is a random string
```